# I have a progressDailog in my webview with setCancelable(false), When I press back button it doesnot go back neither dismisses the progressDialog

Tags: android

Here is the code:

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
progressDialog.show();

        // Start timeout runnable after 3 seconds
        handler = new Handler();
        timeoutRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Change the text of the ProgressDialog
                progressDialog.setMessage("Taking longer to load...");
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(timeoutRunnable, 3000); // 3 seconds delay
    
        // Load the webpage in WebView
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com");
    }
    
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    
            // Cancel the timeout runnable when the page is finished loading
            handler.removeCallbacks(timeoutRunnable);
    
            // Dismiss the ProgressDialog
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        isBackPressed = true;
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

I have tried this code but not working. What I want to achieve is that the progressDialog should be set to setCancelable(false) and if backpressed it should cancel the progressDialog and return to the previous activity.

Comment: Why do you need to have `setCancelable(false)`? It is literally the only thing preventing the `progressDialog` from canceling when the `back` button is pressed.

Comment: @KompjoeFriek I don't want to set it as false, I want a way around if backpressed than it should cancel the progressDialog and return to previous activity in a single tap. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Update your backpressed function and ensure that it is inside the activity class:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ~~~~~~~~

    super.onBackPressed(); //it defines that the default behavior of finishing the activity is preserved along with any additional custom functionality you have added.
}
```

Comment: Not working. Tried your code.